# After installed android in MyEclipse9.1, cannot find Android SDK and AVD Manager in Window Menu

Tags: android, myeclipse

After installed android in MyEclipse9.1, cannot find Android SDK and AVD Manager in Window Menu.

In Window->Preference ,I can see the Android listed in the left column. Then I set the SDK Location accordingly.

When I want to set up the AVD, I can not find the AVD Manager in Window Menu.How can I set up the AVD Manager?

Any thing I may missed?

Comment: have you installed adt properly?

Comment: Update ADT plugin for eclipse. http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: I tried to update but error occured:

Comment: I tried to update but error occured: "Only one of the following can be installed at once: Eclipse UI3.6.1.M20100826-1330  , Eclipse UI3.6.2M20110203....."  . But I can not choose when i try to update?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you open SDK and AVD Manager from your start menu if you are using windows.Have you downloaded the android sdk kit?if yes you will find them.

Comment: I down loaded the adt-buddle-windows-x86-20130219 and run the SDK Manager.exe. and I also down loaded the ADT-21.1.0 which was installed in MyEclipse. I can not find SDK and AVD Manager in my start menu.

Comment: it looks like your adt bundle is out-of-date with the adt plugin.Make sure your sdk tools and adt plugin both are of the same version.Update your eclipse or whatever is required.

Comment: better you update your eclipse by go to "help" menu and select "Update" of "Check for updates",etc

Answer (score 0):

You need **"ADT"** plugin for eclipse.Better you refer the [Android ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

After installing ADT you try to create some sample android application